# Adaptive vs Non Adaptive System

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm

Assume there is a website that generates pages using dynamic technologies: ASP, JSP, etc.

In a non-adaptive website, I may have a code like if condition 1, then generate page A. If condition 2, generate page B and so on.

In an adaptive system, what is the similar logic? is it correct to say if by evaluating context, user request, etc (in a sense if condition 1), the solution is adaptation policy should generate page A to ensure goal of serving the right page is consistent?

I'd be grateful if you could help me understand the difference / similarities.
Heike

P.S. I am reading about self adaptive systems and just needed to point out that this is not a homework question :)

Comment: what are you reading about adaptive systems? why do you need adaptive systems?

Comment: would like to know more on various adaptive systems, so just covering basic defs. But very interested to know more on applications like adaptive e-health, etc. All pointers to interesting applications is EXTREMELY appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition for adaptive ? in my point of view , the first case is adaptive also

Comment: Your question is *EXTREMELY* vague. Your understanding of adaptive system, as presented in your question description, is different from what academic and industry communities understand of it. You can check more definitions on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_system) and improve your question.

Comment: Grateful for the replies and the links suggested. After some basic reading, I learnt that most adaptive systems follow a MAPE loop. In my question I tried to learn how such a loop is explained in adaptive websites. Context changes and sensors get that. Analysis is performed and the plan suggests that page A should be generated to ensure consistency. The effect is that page A is created. I hope my question is more clear and someone could help me see if I am correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about self-adaptive system in the [IBM site](http://www.research.ibm.com/autonomic/) about [autonomic computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomic_computing).

> The Vision: Systems manage themselves according to an administrator's
>   goals. New components integrate as effortlessly as a new cell
>   establishes itself in the human body. These ideas are not science
>   fiction, but elements of the grand challenge to create self-managing
>   computing systems.